# Launching a python script in a new terminal from another python script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm using LXDE, I would like to Launch a python script in a new terminal from another python script.

I would like the new python script to be totally independent.

I have tried a lot of things... 
Calling xterm (or x-terminal-emulator) directly from python with the subprocess.call or subprocess.Popen with or without shell=True argument, it didn't work. It gives me an error about display not being set.

I have also created a sh file which calls the other python script and tried to call it, same results.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Shall the scripts run parallel? Do you just want to have a new window? Do you need the new window or do you just want parallelism?

Comment: I need a new terminal for the script output

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

blocking:

```
import os
os.system("xterm -e \"python christmaskittens.py\"")
```

non blocking:

```
import os
os.system("xterm -e \"python christmaskittens.py\" &")
```